# Folder deleted on network share

Tags: samba, directory

We have a strange problem in our company. Sometimes it happens that a folder it's been deleted from our NAS. It's happened 2 times this month, 1 st time samba logs identified client_A, the second one it identified client_B...

Owners of the clients said that they were at lunch or that they didn't had any access to this folder...

How i can find the problem? Why it happens on the same folder from different clients?

Comment: Do you believe your users? Anyway...scan their pc with antivirus!

Comment: CAT-LIKE TYPING DETECTED http://www.bitboost.com/pawsense/

Answer (score 5):

First of all as House MD says "everybody lies".

Logs, on the other hand, don't lie. If you see user A in logs, that means user A deleted the folder/file, or someone else had access to user A's credentials (or computer).

And one more thing ... users like hitting buttons at random. I also had deleted files/folders on my NAS and noone took the "credit" for the action ... than, a few days/weeks later while I was troubleshooting a user, I observed that he tried to use some shortcuts and sometimes it worked, sometimes he miss-hit some buttons and got an attention/messagebox and hit "YES" by default ...

Users don't read messageboxes ... so if you want to be safe, don't let them delete important stuff and make regular backups.

Comment: Sometimes they don't even delete them, they just fail at double clicking and drag the folder off it to some other obscure folder.

Comment: @The Digital Ninja, I had a boss that dragged folders at least once a month.